# Error while debugged

Tags: asp.net

What does this error means? 'Admin_ManageInvtry.' is not a valid value for attribute 'inherits'.  I've already view the code, remove and redo the page but still get the same error. Can someone please tell me why. Thanks.

Comment: Try cleaning your solution. Close and reopen your visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set value of `Inherits` attribute with the name of partial class in code-behind.

For instance, here is code in code-behind

```
public partial class Sample : System.Web.UI.Page{ ...}
```

and .aspx markup must be,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" .... Inherits="Sample" %>
```